# How to get the actual utterance text of an Alexa skill intent using JOVO framework

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

Is there a way to get the actual Alexa utterance (the actual question or phrase user has asked) using JOVO? I need to alter the speech output based on that. Here is a use case scenario:

Variations:

**Utterance:** *How many active coupons*
**Alexa:** *At present, you have 2 active coupons. Do you want more details?*
**Utterance:** *Yes*
**Alexa:** *Currently you have 2 active coupons running. WINTER20 with a 10 per cent discount, which expires on February 20, 2020. SPRING20 with a flat INR 250 discount on all products above INR 1000. Expires on April 30, 2020.*

**Utterance:** *Get my coupon details*
**Alexa:** *Currently you have 2 active coupons running. WINTER20 with a 10 per cent discount, which expires on February 20, 2020. SPRING20 with a flat INR 250 discount on all products above INR 1000. Expires on April 30, 2020.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the exact text or question that a user asked from Alexa. Your skill will only receive the intent name and any associated slot values (if filled).

However, you could adapt your interaction model to fit your use-cases. For example, you could create an `GetActiveCouponIntent` and `GetCouponDetailsIntent` with different sample utterances. 
Then, if the user triggers the `GetActiveCouponIntent` intent, you can set a session attribute indicating the state. If the user then triggers the `AMAZON.YesIntent` you can evaluate the state attribute and change the output accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it might be a useful feature in Alexa especially for complex models. Session handling is what I am doing at present.